# TextFormField in a Positioned widget doesnt open to write

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make an UI design. When I wrap my Container with Positioned widget my TextFormField shows but doesnt open any keyboard, I can't click on the field. When I remove the stack TextFormField works but I need to use Stack. What should I do?

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
```

Here is the Stack widget

```
      body: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          BuildBG(),
          BuildForm(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class BuildForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Here is the Positioned widget

```
    return Positioned(
      top: 250,
      left: 25,
      child: Container(
        height: 340,
        width: 340,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 5)
            ]),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Text(
                  "WELCOME BACK!",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Container(
                child: TextFormField(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I looked in internet couldnt find anything.Please help

Comment: Could you add your BuildBG() widget?

Comment: I solved it. I changed Positioned widget to Align then then give Alignment.center widget to its parameter "align" . After I add padding to Container. It solved. I hope this will help to somebody

Comment: Cool. I guess you can achieve the same result using `fit: StackFit.expand`.